# automatically getting data as it is posted without refreshing with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a conversation system with php jQuery and ajax.
I am using the following jQuery to handle the ajax post together with php.

```
 function replyToStatus(sid,user,ta,postuser){
    var data = $('#'+ta).val(); 
    if(data.trim() == ""){
        alert("Please type a reply before you submit.");
        return false;
    }else{
    var dataString = 'action=status_reply&sid='+sid+'&user='+user+'&postuser='+postuser+'&data='+data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: location.href,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
          $('#'+ta).val("");
          $( "#conrep_"+sid ).append( '<li><div class="comment-user-image-container"><div class="user-image" style="background:url(\'imagesrc.jpg\');"></div></div><div class="comment-content"><h5><a href="">admin </a>'+data+'</h5><img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="userimagesrc.jpg"></div></li>');

        }
    });

}
}
```

This code appends and displays the post immediately to the current user(user1) making the post.However to all the other users viewing the same page whom have not refreshed the page after this user(user1) has posted ,this post won't appear until they have refreshed.
My question is how do I make a system that will automatically show this post to all users or how do I deal with this problem otherwise.
Thanks for the reply in advance:)

Comment: `Long-polling`, `web-sockets` etc

Comment: Look into web sockets. http://socketo.me/

Comment: you can also use javascript setInterval() for checking database every while . but the excelent way is using websockets

Comment: for push from PHP, i recommend EventSource, which is much easier to implement than WebSockets and gives you the server push capability you need.